Proofs with summations ∑ in Lean 4
The following is a toy example:
I have a function defined over a finite domain. This function satisfies the property if the summation of its applications across the entire domain is less than or equal to 3.
Below is the corresponding code:
import Mathlib
open Finset BigOperators




structure BasicStruct (α : Type) where
  toFun : α → Nat
  finite_domain : Fintype α

def BasicStruct.satisfiesProperty {α : Type} [Fintype α] (c : BasicStruct α) : Prop :=
  ∑ a : α, c.toFun a ≤ 3


inductive SimpleAlpha where
  | a : SimpleAlpha
  | b : SimpleAlpha
deriving BEq, Repr, Fintype, DecidableEq, Ord

def func : SimpleAlpha → Nat
  | SimpleAlpha.a => 1
  | SimpleAlpha.b => 2

def simpleStruct : BasicStruct SimpleAlpha :=
  {
  toFun := func
  finite_domain := inferInstance
  }

I would like to prove that simpleStruct satisfies the property:
theorem simpleStruct_satisfies_property : simpleStruct.satisfiesProperty := by
  sorry

I am unsure how to proceed with the proof.

I am not sure I will propose the most idioamtic solution, but I can at least explain how to think about the problem. If we just plug in all the definitions then we can simply compute the result, i.e., we'll get 3 ≤ 3, which is trivially true. This leads to:
theorem simpleStruct_satisfies_property : simpleStruct.satisfiesProperty := by
  unfold BasicStruct.satisfiesProperty
  trivial

We could replace trivial with rfl or decide, and it would still work. If we mark BasicStruct.satisfiesProperty as reducible, then we needn't unfold:
@[reducible]
def BasicStruct.satisfiesProperty {α : Type} [Fintype α] (c : BasicStruct α) : Prop :=
  ∑ a : α, c.toFun a ≤ 3

-- definitions omitted

theorem simpleStruct_satisfies_property : simpleStruct.satisfiesProperty := by
  trivial

Again, rfl and decide could be used in place of trivial.

Thanks. This decide is exactly what I needed to know!

@JavierBurroni note that decide is orthogonal to the fact that the key reason why the result is true is computation. In general, Lean gives you a somewhat fine grained control over what to compute (which is why, in the first version, you have to manually unfold). However, if you just want things to compute, and then conclude, you can use the with_unfolding_all tactic, ie. with_unfolding_all rfl or with_unfolding_all decide. Note that, conveniently enough, with_unfolding_all rfl can also be written rfl'.

I knew my solution wasn't idiomatic enough. Thanks, @jthulhu!

Thanks @jthulhu for the extra comments!
